# Getting NaN while implementing Linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to implement linear regression in R. Below is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame()

df<-cbind(c(10000,20000,5000,5123,5345,5454,11000,23000,6000,6100,6300),
c(5600,21000,1000,2000,2300,3000,7000,21400,3200,3250,3300))

df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("Population","Profit")

plot(df,df$Population,df$Profit)

X<-df$Population
Y<-df$Profit
X<-cbind(1,X)
theta<-c(0,0)
m<-nrow(X)
cost=sum(((X %*% theta)-Y)^2)/(2*m)
alpha<-0.001
iterations<-1500

for(i in 1:iterations){
  temp1 <- theta[1] - alpha * (1/m) * sum(((X%*%theta)- Y))
  temp2 <- theta[2] <- theta[2] - alpha * (1/m) * sum(((X%*%theta)- Y)*X[,2])
  theta[1] = temp1
  theta[2] = temp2
}
```

But am getting theta values as NaN. Need help in understanding why am getting NaN.

Comment: The reason is that `temp1` and `temp2` becomes infinite at some point in the loop and this creates the `NaN` in the subsequent iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the `print` for one of the 'temp', the values are getting to infinite at certain point and then for the next iteration onwards it becomes NaN

```
iterations <- 62

for(i in 1:iterations){
  temp1 <- theta[1] - alpha * (1/m) * sum(((X%*%theta)- Y))
  temp2 <- theta[2] <- theta[2] - alpha * (1/m) * sum(((X%*%theta)- Y)*X[,2])
  print(temp1)
  #print(temp2)
  theta[1] = temp1
  theta[2] = temp2
}
```

-print output

```
#[1] 6.640909
#[1] -981047.5
#[1] 122403140248
#[1] -1.527201e+16
#[1] 1.90546e+21
#[1] -2.377406e+26
#[1] 2.966245e+31
#[1] -3.700928e+36
#[1] 4.617578e+41
#...
#...
#[1] 1.894035e+286
#[1] -2.363151e+291
#[1] 2.948459e+296
#[1] -3.678737e+301
#[1] Inf
#[1] NaN
```

Comment: From very first value i got NaN, which should not be a case because i calculated manually and it is coming approx. 6

Comment: I retried with your code as well and output is same .                              
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN
[1] NaN

Comment: @NeerajSharma  The reason is that you are not updating the `theta<-c(0,0)` If the theta is already NaN at the beginning, it will always give that values

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake. I am getting values, but they does not seems to be correct theta values. Need to look further on gradient descent implementation. Thank you again.